# Download a dynamically generated csv from external website ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, csv, download

I have a URL that I can hit through a browser which will download a csv to my computer. I'd like to automate that process though. It's an external website, and the file is served over https, I'm using Ruby.

The URL looks something like this:
https://example.com/functionGenerateReport?reportFormat=CSV&date=2015%2F03%2F05

I've been trying to use open-uri to get this downloaded.

At first I was throwing this error:

```
OpenSSL::SSL::SSLError - SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=SSLv3 read server certificate B: certificate verify failed
```

So I modified my open function to be

```
open(url, {:ssl_verify_mode => OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_NONE}
```

Now I'm running into this error:

```
OpenURI::HTTPError - 401 Unauthorized
```

Has anyone done something like this before that was able to get a csv downloaded?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is mean that authentication required. Probably this is `basic authentication` then just specify user and password as described [here](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/open-uri/rdoc/OpenURI/OpenRead.html) for `http_basic_authentication` option.

In other case try to determine authentication type.